# Default app icon on app switch

Tags: android

I just replaced the default icons (mipmap) in my AndroidStudio Projekt.
The icon in my launcher's menu is the new one, but if I change to the homescreen and try to switch back to my app the icon is still the default on.
What am I doing wrong?

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="korn.at.lazyalarm" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever"></receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher", you mean you don't see ic_launcher in the homescreen?

Comment: what I mean is, the the icon is different in the app switch menu (long press of the home button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean & rebuild your project, when you replace existing mipmap icon using the same name it does not work until you rebuild project